# Menu Layout works in all browsers EXCEPT iPhone

Tags: iphone, safari, css

I have a menu very similar to the menu here on StackOverflow.  The problem is that my menu looks right in every browser I've tested it on EXCEPT for my iPhone.

Here is a screenshot of the iPhone
[image: iphone menu]

Now obviously the "Add Event" button is supposed to be the same size as the rest.

Here's my Markup

```
        <div id="menucontainer">
            <div class="floatleft">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><%: Html.NavigationLink("Now", "Index", "Events")%></li>
                    <li><%: Html.NavigationLink("Coming", "Coming", "Events")%></li>
                    <li><%: Html.NavigationLink("Hot", "Hot", "Events")%></li>
                    <li><%: Html.NavigationLink("Tags", "Index", "Tags")%></li>
                    <li><%: Html.NavigationLink("Users", "Index", "Users")%></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="floatright">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><%: Html.NavigationLink("Add Event", "AddEvent", "Events")%></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here's my CSS

```
#menucontainer{position:relative; width:675px; float:right;}
ul.menu
{
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.menu li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.menu li a
{
    padding: 8px 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-shadow:#000 0px 1px 1px;
}

ul.menu li a.youarehere
{
    background-color:@brand_color;
    color: #fff;
}

ul.menu li a:hover
{
    background-color:@brand_color;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li a:active
{
    background-color:@brand_color;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a
{
    background-color:@brand_color;
    color: #000;
}
.floatright
{
    float: right;
}
.floatleft
{
    float: left;
}
```

Unfortunately I can't figure this one out.  Thanks in advance for any direction.

## EDIT:

This is the final output being sent to the browser

```
        <div id="menucontainer">
            <div class="floatleft">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a class="youarehere" href="/">Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/events/coming">Coming</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/events/hot">Hot</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/tags">Tags</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="floatright">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="/events/addevent">Add Event</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

## EDIT:

Reproduction on jsbin
http://jsbin.com/akadi3/2 (note: obviously you need the iOS browser to see the problem)

Comment: This hardly relates to ASP.NET MVC. Please post your final markup as rendered by the browser.

Comment: I wonder if the CSS classes floatleft and floatright have anything to do with the layout?  Can you post those as well?

Comment: @Mike, Done... @Darin, Done...

Comment: Here's a fiddle link so I can check on my iphone: http://jsfiddle.net/YStVK/

Comment: I can view the button "add event" correctly with my iphone and the code you gave. Check it at http://jsbin.com/akadi3 Can you give as a working example of the problem?

Comment: see my edit.  I reproduced the issue on jsbin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after a LOT of fiddling around, it appears as though if I add a `height` attribute to the `menucontainer`, then I'm all good.

```
#menucontainer
{
    position:relative;
    width:675px;
    height:40px; /* this fixed the problem */
    float:right;
    font-size:80%;
}
```